# UIView to UIImage without subviews and hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

I've got a UIView that I draw on just like a fingerpainting app, but, it's invisible sometimes. And I want to be able to take a screenshot of it when it's invisible. Also, I want a screenshot of it when it is visible however I dont want any of the subviews. I only want the UIView itself. Here's somethings I've tried:

```
func shapshot() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return nil
    }
    self.layer.render(in: context)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if image == nil {
        return nil
    }

//  if !SettingsManager.shared.isColorInverted {
    //return image!.invertedImage()
//  }
 return image
}

func snapshot() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, self.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

Both aren't working.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
       func snapshot() -> UIImage {
     let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
     self.btnShare.isHidden = true
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()   
    return image!

    }
```